# JavaScript: Change Json data array into new format

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, mapping

I am trying to work with a json data which needs to be changed in many ways.

My current json data is following:

```
{
  "file1": {
    "function1": {
      "calls": {
        "105:4": {
          "file": "file2",
          "function": "function5"
        },
        "106:4": {
          "file": "file2",
          "function": "function6"
        }
      },
      "lines1": {
        "123": "102:0",
        "456": "105:8"
      },
      "lines2": {
        "102:0": [
          "102:0"
        ],
        "105:4": [
          "106:4",
          "107:1"
        ],
        "106:4": [
          "107:1"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I want the data as following:

```
{
  "name": "program",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "file1",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "function1",
          "calls": [
            {
              "line": 105,
              "file": "file2",
              "function": "function5"
            },
            {
              "line": 106,
              "file": "file2",
              "function": "function6"
            }
          ],
          "lines1": [
            102,
            105
          ],
          "lines2": [
            [
              102,
              102
            ],
            [
              105,
              106,
              107
            ],
            [
              106,
              107
            ]
          ],
          "group": 1
        }
      ],
      "group": 1
    }
  ],
  "group": 0
}
```

Here, number of files and functions are more. The value of first name is user defined. The group information is depend on the parent-child. Each file will have a group ascending group number and all the functions inside the file will also have the same group number. For the values for lines the first part before : are taken (104:4 becomes 104).

I have tried with following code so far, which is incomplete and not handling group information correctly.

```
function build(data) {
    return Object.entries(data).reduce((r, [key, value], idx) => {
      const obj = {
        name: 'program',
        children: [],
        group: 0,
        lines: []
      }

      if (key !== 'lines2) {
        obj.name = key;
        obj.children = build(value)
          if(!(key.includes(":")))
          obj.group = idx + 1;
      } else {
        if (!obj.lines) obj.lines = [];
        Object.entries(value).forEach(([k, v]) => {
          obj.lines.push([k, ...v].map(e => e.split(':').shift()))
        })
      }

      r.push(obj)
      return r;
    }, [])
  }

  const result = build(data);
  console.log(result);
```

I would really appreciate if you can help me out. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the structure of your input is consistenly defined as shown in your question (ie, that no "saftey checks" are needed, etc), then you could approach this using a combination of [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) as shown below.

See inline documentation in this code snippet for details on how to achieve that:

```js
function transformData(data, programName) {

  /* Define local parse helper to extract number from NUMBER:STRING format */    
  const parseHelper = (str) => Number.parseInt(str.split(':')[0]);
      
  /* Define local parse helper to extract group number from STRINGNUMBER 
  format */    
  const parseGroup = (str) => Number.parseInt(str.replace(/^[a-z]+/,""))
      
  /* Create a root object with specified program name */
  return {
    name : programName,
    
    /* Iterate each file name and object entry of input */
    children : Object.entries(input).map(([fileName, fileObject]) => {

      /* Iterate function name and object of current file object */
      const fileChildren = Object.entries(fileObject)
        .map(([functionName, functionObject]) => {

        /* Iterate function name and object of current file object */
        const lines = Object.entries(functionObject)
          .reduce((target, [functionKey, functionValue]) => {

            if(functionKey === "calls") {

              /* If function key is calls, interpret this value as data to be
              transformed to desired calls object shape */
              const calls = Object.entries(functionValue)
                .map(([callKey, callObject]) => {

                return {
                  line : parseHelper(callKey),
                  file : callObject['file'],
                  function : callObject['function']
                }
              });
              
              /* Inject calls object into lines result */
              return {
                ...target,
                calls
              };
            }
            else {

              /* Otherwise, interpret this value as data to be transformed to 
                 desired lines object shape */
              const lineValues = Object.entries(functionValue)
                .map(([key, value]) => {

                /* If value is an array, map key/value pair to a nested array
                   in resulting linesValues array */
                return Array.isArray(value) ? [key, ...value]
                 .map(parseHelper) : parseHelper(value)
              })

              /* Inject line values into function key of result */
              return {
                ...target,
                [functionKey] : lineValues
              }
            }

        }, {});
        
        /* Inject lines into function result */
        return {
          name : functionName,
          ...lines,
          group : parseGroup(functionName)
        }
      });

      /* Map file object to name/children pairing */
      return { 
        name : fileName,
        children : fileChildren,
          group : parseGroup(fileName)
      }
    }),
    
    group : 0
  }
}

const input = {
  "file1": {
    "function1": {
      "calls": {
        "105:4": {
          "file": "file2",
          "function": "function5"
        },
        "106:4": {
          "file": "file2",
          "function": "function6"
        }
      },
      "lines1": {
        "123": "102:0",
        "456": "105:8"
      },
      "lines2": {
        "102:0": [
          "102:0"
        ],
        "105:4": [
          "106:4",
          "107:1"
        ],
        "106:4": [
          "107:1"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
};

console.log(transformData(input, "program"))
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much !! 
But group information is not there :(

Comment: You're welcome - sorry to miss that, just updated the answer. Does that help?

Comment: I am so sorry. The json output is correct but this new structure is not working with my existing d3 code. 
Its showing following error:
Argument of type '{ name: string; children: { group: number; name: string; }[]; group: number; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly string[]'.
  Type '{ name: string; children: { group: number; name: string; }[]; group: number; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Can you please help me out? :(

Comment: I just wanted to access the children from the data which is the output of your code by
        const colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(data.children)
        .range(d3.schemeCategory10);

Comment: Are you able to post a new question with the D3 code and send me a link to that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59449930/argument-of-type-is-not-assignable-to-string-d3 is the link for new question. The existing code is long, so I gave snippet of it. Its the first lines. I hope its okay.

Comment: It looks like someone else to go it before me :-)

Comment: You're welcome - all the best with your project :-)