# Argument of type is not assignable to string

Tags: javascript, json, string, object, d3.js

I have a formatted json data that I want to use in d3 to draw a hierarchy. It was working with old data but after adding more dimension in the json data, its giving following error.

Argument of type '{ name: string; children: { group: number; name: string; }[]; group: number; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly string[]'.
Type '{ name: string; children: { group: number; name: string; }[]; group: number; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.

The output of my reformatted data is following which is generated by using the code from @Dacre Denny's answer from  [Change Json data into new format by JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59448748/change-json-data-into-new-format-by-javascript/59448945?noredirect=1#comment105082157_59448945) link

```
{
  name: "program",
  children: (1)[
    {
      name: "file1",
      children: (1)[
        {
          name: "function1",
          calls: (2)[
            {
              line: 105,
              file: "file2",
              function: "function5"
            },
            {
              line: 106,
              file: "file2",
              function: "function6"
            }
          ],
          point: (2)[
            102,
            105
          ],
          point2: (3)[
            (2)[
              102,
              102
            ],
            (3)[
              105,
              106,
              107
            ],
            (2)[
              106,
              107
            ]
          ],
          group: 1
        }
      ],
      group: 1
    }
  ],
  group: 0
}
```

My existing code snippet for d3 is following:

```
const data = TestFunction.test(); //from here i am calling the reformatted output
const root = d3.hierarchy(data);

const colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(data.children) // here its showing the error.
        .range(d3.schemeCategory10);
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a nested array to `ordinal.domain()`: an ordinal scale needs to have a **plain** array as the domain... even more important, an array of **values**, i.e., primitives, like strings (if you pass numbers they will be stringified anyway...). That explains your error: *"Argument of type is not assignable to **string**"*.

That being said, you can use `root.descendants()` to get all the children and `map` to get their desired properties. In your case, I'll assume that the string you want is the children's `name` property.

In this demo, `myNames` is the array you'll pass to the ordinal scale (if you don't want the root's name, remove it):

```js
const data = {
  "name": "program",
  "children": [{
    "name": "file1",
    "children": [{
      "name": "function1",
      "calls": [{
          "line": 105,
          "file": "file2",
          "function": "function5"
        },
        {
          "line": 106,
          "file": "file2",
          "function": "function6"
        }
      ],
      "lines1": [
        102,
        105
      ],
      "lines2": [
        [
          102,
          102
        ],
        [
          105,
          106,
          107
        ],
        [
          106,
          107
        ]
      ],
      "group": 1
    }],
    "group": 1
  }],
  "group": 0
};

const root = d3.hierarchy(data);

const myNames = root.descendants().map(d => d.data.name);

console.log(myNames)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I was thinking this nested data as the problem but wasn't sure.